# infinite value-crossings for continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

The $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ function 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x = 0 \\
x \sin \frac{1}{x} & x \ne 0\end{cases}
$$
crosses the horizontal line $y = 0$ infinitely often. (It happens to cross many other horizontal lines infinitely often, but its restriction to any closed interval does not cross any others infinitely often, which is what interests me.)

If we define $$g(x) = f(x) + x f(x-\pi),$$ then $g$ crosses both $y = 0$ and $y = \pi$ infinitely often. Clearly, I can construct, by analogous methods, functions on closed intervals that cross any finite number of lines infinitely often. (And $f$ itself does so for every horizontal line, once we remove the restriction of the closed-interval domain.)

This motivates me to ask:

Suppose that $f : [0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ is continuous. Is it possible for the preimages of infinitely many points in $\Bbb R$ to each be infinite? Is it possible for the preimages of uncountably many points in $\Bbb R$ to be infinite?

I have a feeling that this should actually be an easy analysis question, but ... it's been too long since I studied analysis.

The motivation:

In [Closed loop on the sphere is homotopic to a product of homeomorphisms onto great arcs of the sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331216/closed-loop-on-the-sphere-is-homotopic-to-a-product-of-homeomorphisms-onto-great/2331251#2331251), the poster mistakenly believed that a space-filling curve on the sphere must "cross from $U$ to $V$ infinitely often", where $U$ and $V$ are two open sets that form a cover of the sphere, and while I was able to address the misunderstanding, it led me to the question above.

Comment: Well, the function restricted to $\;[-0.5,\,0.5]\;$ **still** crosses the line $\;y=0\;$ infinitely many times...

Comment: Yes, but my question is whether it's possible to find a function on a closed interval that crosses *infinitely many* horizontal lines infinitely often.

Comment: I understood that. I wrote the above because of your parentheses in your 3-4th lines.

Comment: I believe $y=sin(\frac1x)$ crosses all the horizontal lines $< 1$ and $> -1$ infinitely often in the domain $[0,\epsilon]$ where epsilon is an arbitrarily small positive real number.

Comment: Not continuous at $x = 0$.

Comment: @donantonio: fixed, I hope.

Comment: There is a continuous $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ such that for any neighborhood $U$ of any $x\in [0,1],$ the set $\{y\in U: f(y)=f(x)\}$ has the same cardinal as $\mathbb R.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  Why is there such a function? Proof?

Comment: Ah...the Weierstrass function. Of course!

Comment: @DonAntonio . The example I was thinking of  is $f(g(x))$ where $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ is the Peano space-filling curve and $f:[0,1]^2\to [0,1$] is the projection  to the first co-ordinate.  For $n\in \mathbb N$ and integer $ j$ with $0\leq j<4^n, $the image $g([j4^{-n},(j+1)4^{-n}])$  is a square $[a2^{-n},(a+1)2^{-n}]\times [b2^{-n},(b+1)2^{-n}]$ for some integers $a, b$ with $0\leq a<2^n$ and $0\leq b<2^n.$

Comment: Nice example, Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: It seems to me that the  [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) has the property that for almost every point in the codomain, the preimage is infinite. As the Wikipedia page points out, "between any two points no matter how close, the function will not be monotone." This may be sufficient to prove the claim, or it may require a slightly more detailed analysis.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the claim that the preimage of almost every point is infinite? This is not quite the same as saying that the function is not monotone on any interval.

Comment: I agree it's not quite the same, and I don't, offhand, have a solid proof. Nor do I have time, right now, to try to produce one, so for now, my "answer" must be regarded as a "suggestion" rather than an answer. I've edited to reflect this.